# Pandas: GroupData & Manipulate values within groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, and taking a subset of it, it has a dict constructor like:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'K': {8: 3.9274999999999998, 9: 1.9275, 10: 2.9274999999999998, 11: 2.9274999999999998, 12: 2.275, 13: 3.2750000000000004, 14: 2.775, 15: 2.8000000000000003, 16: 1.7999999999999998, 17: 2.8000000000000003, 18: 2.82, 19: 2.82, 20: 2.8000000000000003, 21: 2.8000000000000003, 22: 2.82, 23: 2.82, 24: 1.82, 25: 1.82, 26: 1.7999999999999998}, 'Struct': {8: 'Call', 9: 'Put', 10: 'Straddle', 11: 'Straddle', 12: 'Put', 13: 'Call', 14: 'Straddle', 15: 'Delta', 16: 'Put', 17: 'Put', 18: 'Put', 19: 'Delta', 20: 'Put', 21: 'Delta', 22: 'Delta', 23: 'Put', 24: 'Put', 25: 'Put', 26: 'Put'}, 'MainID': {8: 10, 9: 10, 10: 10, 11: 10, 12: 20, 13: 20, 14: 20, 15: 21, 16: 21, 17: 21, 18: 23, 19: 23, 20: 23, 21: 23, 22: 23, 23: 23, 24: 23, 25: 23, 26: 23}})
```

Markdown

| Index | K | Struct | MainID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 3.9275 | Call | 10 |
| 9 | 1.9275 | Put | 10 |
| 10 | 2.9275 | Straddle | 10 |
| 11 | 2.9275 | Straddle | 10 |
| 12 | 2.275 | Put | 20 |
| 13 | 3.275 | Call | 20 |
| 14 | 2.775 | Straddle | 20 |
| 15 | 2.8 | Delta | 21 |
| 16 | 1.8 | Put | 21 |
| 17 | 2.8 | Put | 21 |
| 18 | 2.82 | Put | 23 |
| 19 | 2.82 | Delta | 23 |
| 20 | 2.8 | Put | 23 |
| 21 | 2.8 | Delta | 23 |
| 22 | 2.82 | Delta | 23 |
| 23 | 2.82 | Put | 23 |
| 24 | 1.82 | Put | 23 |
| 25 | 1.82 | Put | 23 |
| 26 | 1.8 | Put | 23 |

I am trying to find a way to do the following steps:

1. Groupby("MainID")
2. For any Call or Put, subtract "K" from either "Straddle", or "Delta" if it exists within the Groupby("MainID")
3. In the case that you have multiple delta/put/call within a Groupby("MainID"), you would want to subtract based on ascending values.  Ie, if K[Struct==Put] = [1,2,3] and K[Struct==Delta] = [2,2,3] the result would be [-1, 0, 0]

The resulting DF would look like

| Index | K | Struct | MainID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | Call | 10 |
| 9 | -1 | Put | 10 |
| 10 | 2.9275 | Straddle | 10 |
| 11 | 2.9275 | Straddle | 10 |
| 12 | -0.50 | Put | 20 |
| 13 | 0.50 | Call | 20 |
| 14 | 2.775 | Straddle | 20 |
| 15 | 2.8 | Delta | 21 |
| 16 | -1 | Put | 21 |
| 17 | 0 | Put | 21 |
| 18 | 0 | Put | 23 |
| 19 | 2.82 | Delta | 23 |
| 20 | 0 | Put | 23 |
| 21 | 2.8 | Delta | 23 |
| 22 | 2.82 | Delta | 23 |
| 23 | 0 | Put | 23 |
| 24 | -1 | Put | 23 |
| 25 | -1 | Put | 23 |
| 26 | -1 | Put | 23 |

Thanks so much!  It's a tricky one...

Comment: Why is the last entry K value not -1.02?

Comment: Hmm, did I mess up the example values?  It should be three sets, like: (delta, put, put). 2 of value (2.82, 2.82. 1.82) and (2.80,2.80,1.80)